# How to pass multiple arguments to dask.distributed.Client().map?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

```
import dask.distributed
def f(x, y):
    return x, y
client = dask.distributed.Client()
client.map(f, [(1, 2), (2, 3)])
```

Does not work.

```
[<Future: status: pending, key: f-137239e2f6eafbe900c0087f550bc0ca>,
 <Future: status: pending, key: f-64f918a0c730c63955da91694fcf7acc>]

distributed.worker - WARNING -  Compute Failed
Function:  f
args:      ((1, 2))
kwargs:    {}
Exception: TypeError("f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'",)

distributed.worker - WARNING -  Compute Failed
Function:  f
args:      ((2, 3))
kwargs:    {}
Exception: TypeError("f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'",)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do not quite have the signature right - perhaps the doc is not clear (suggestions welcome). `Client.map()` takes (variable number of) sets of arguments for each task submitted, not a single iterable thing. You should phrase this as

```
client.map(f, (1, 2), (2, 3))
```

or, if you wanted to stay closer to your original pattern

```
client.map(f, *[(1, 2), (2, 3)])
```

Comment: And is there a way to pass kwargs as as in a list of dicts.

Comment: No, I don't think so, you can only pass kwargs to all function calls. You will have to modify your target function a bit and have your extra parameters be part of the args as above.

Comment: @mdurant I still don't understand, your example works but `client.map(f, (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4))` doesn't.

Comment: Those two do look the same - but Dask does specifically care about tuples, so there must be a type-check somewhere.

Comment: @mdurant and `client.map(f, (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4))` works fine.

Comment: OK :)  Just the order of iteration, then.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, the [documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html#distributed.Client.map) is definitely a bit confusing on this one. And I couldn't find an example that clearly demonstrated this problem. So let me break it down below:

```
def test_fn(a, b, c, d, **kwargs):
    return a + b + c + d + kwargs["special"]

futures = client.map(test_fn, *[[1, 2, 3, 4], (1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4)], special=100)
output = [f.result() for f in futures]
# output = [104, 108, 112, 116]

futures = client.map(test_fn, [1, 2, 3, 4], (1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4), special=100)
output = [f.result() for f in futures]
# output = [104, 108, 112, 116]
```

Things to note:

1. Doesn't matter if you use lists or tuples. And like I did above, you can mix them.
2. You have to group arguments by their position. So if you're passing in 4 sets of arguments, the first list will contain the first argument from all 4 sets. (In this case, the "first" call to `test_fn` gets a=b=c=d=1.)
3. Extra `**kwargs` (like `special`) are passed through to the function. But it'll be the same value for all function calls.

Now that I think about it, this isn't *that* surprising. I think it's just following Python's [concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) signature.

PS. Note that even though the documentation says "Returns:
List, iterator, or Queue of futures, depending on the type of the
inputs.", you can actually get this error: `Dask no longer supports mapping over Iterators or Queues. Consider using a normal for loop and Client.submit`

Comment: I think this would be more immediately clear if you used a different number of args than the number of function calls. i.e.  `def test_fcn(a,b): a+b` and `client.map(test_fcn, *[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]])` leads to [2,4,6,8]. +1 most helpful answer.