# Dask map method in fuction with multiple arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, dask, dask-distributed

I want to apply the `Client.map` method to a function that uses multiple arguments as does the `Pool.starmap` method of `multiprocessing`. Here is an example

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

from dask.distributed import Client


@contextmanager
def dask_client(**kwargs):
    """some docs"""
    kwargs.setdefault("ip", "localhost:8786")
    client = Client(**kwargs)

    try:
        yield client
    except Exception:
        raise
    finally:
        client.close()


def f(x,y,z):
    return x+y+z
# Dummy function

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with dask_client() as client:
        client.map(f, (1,2,3), (1,2,3))

distributed.worker - WARNING - Compute Failed
Function:  f
args:      (1, 1)
kwargs:    {}
Exception: TypeError("f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'z'")

distributed.worker - WARNING - Compute Failed
Function:  f
args:      (2, 2)
kwargs:    {}
Exception: TypeError("f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'z'")

distributed.worker - WARNING - Compute Failed
Function:  f
args:      (3, 3)
kwargs:    {}
Exception: TypeError("f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'z'")
```

This was the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54963918/how-to-pass-multiple-arguments-to-dask-distributed-client-map)

I know that each tuple is being viewed as `x` of my function `f`. If possible I don't want a solution like

```
def f(var_list):
    # could be sum(), but this is a dummy example
    return var_list[0] + var_list[1] + var_list[2]
```

Answer (score 5):

You're close, note that there should be the same number of iterables as the arguments in your function:

```py
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client()

def f(x,y,z):
    return x+y+z

futs = client.map(f, *[(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)])

client.gather(futs) # [12, 15, 18]
```

From the comments it seems you want to store all arguments in a single tuple, in that case you can do:

```
# will pass them as x=1, y=2, z=3
long_list = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9), (10,11,12)]

futs = client.map(f, *zip(*long_list))

client.gather(futs) # [6, 15, 24, 33]
```

Comment: This works, but is not what I want. I need the iterables as big as possible, so `map` is not an option.

Comment: Hmmm, do you want something like `def f(*args):`?

Comment: I need this https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap